# Laravel - Driver [] is Not Supported

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ftp

I haven't found an example like mine, the others appear to be missing what I already have but anyways, I'm trying to upload to an external FTP site, to which I have the following in my filesystem.php file:

```
    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    ],

     'fourkites-ftp' => [
        'driver' => 'ftp',
        'host' => 'ftp.site.com',
        'username' => 'my-username',
        'password' => 'my-password',

    ],
```

And I'm trying to send the file along with the following in one of my controllers:

```
  Storage::disk('fourkites-ftp')->put('new/afnloads.csv', $temp);
```

And as I'm trying testing it, it gives me this error:

```
(1/1) InvalidArgumentException 
Driver [] is not supported.
in FilesystemManager.php line 126
```

Are there any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Can you include more of the config? What follows that last `,` in the array?

Comment: Is your config cached?

Comment: have you restart the artisan serve?

Answer (score 12):

Most probably config cached.
Try clear using

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem by following commands

> `php artisan cache:clear`

> `php artisan config:clear`

> `php artisan clear-compiled`

Comment: very simple yet very useful!! thanks alot for sharing

Answer (score -1):

It helped me adding this line to bootstrap/app.php (in 'Create The Application' section)

```
$app->configure('filesystems');
```